# how to get the number infront of a string with js?

Tags: javascript

i need help with a function in javascript.

I have strings like this: `124text` or `12hello`

I need a function which maked the following:

```
foo('124text') -> 123
```

and

```
foo('12hello') -> 12
```

in words: i give it a input string and the function return a integer which is the number infront of this string

how to do it with javascript?

Comment: I tried it with slice but it was to complex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseInt` will do exactly that

```
parseInt('123abc',10) //returns 123 as a number
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/eAe4v/

Comment: this is exactly the thing which i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial application of [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var str, num;
str = "124text";
num = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Or if there might be other digits later in the string that you don't want:

```
var str, num, m;
str = "124text";
m = /^(\d+)/.exec(str);
if (m) {
    num = m[1];
}
```

In both cases, `num` above will still be a string (just a string with only digits in it). Use `num = parseInt(num, 10)` if you want to parse it as a base-10 (decimal) string.